# Java SaaS Architecture - Extensibility

Tags: java, architecture, amazon-ec2, cloud, saas

I am considering building a Java EE based set of services and licensing these services to my clients. While we will aim to make these services generic for any client, reality is that customizations and new services will be needed on a client specific basis.

Likely the stack will be a Java application deployed to the EC2 cloud, possibly leveraging a framework such as Spring.

What architecture would one prescribe to have a hosted application for my clients, but also enable them to build their own custom extensions. Does anyone have technical or business example of a company that has built a hosted SaaS service that is extensible on the platform side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done this yet, but AFAIK you could use module systems such as OSGi also on the server side to write modular, extensible server side applications.

Comment: I have a lot of experience with OSGi and it could be a good fit for what you want to do.  You should research the Whiteboard pattern, as this is a very clean way to provide extension points that can dynamically react to new code being introduced.

Answer (score -1):

[Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.net/) does this. You basically pay to have even its own source code, as well as a Platform SDK, or even a Managed Instance (this one, however, seems not extensible)

Internally, most of them rely in an OSGi Container (I think its Felix), so it manages dependencies accordingly, as well as DI and Extension Points. Perhaps might be worth it to have a try

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question and is likely to be deleted. If you think this information is valuable then you may want to post it as a comment.